# Несколько одинаковых объектов в SortedSet со специфической реализацией IComparer

Tags: c#, коллекции

Мне необходимо создать такую структуру данных, в рамках которой все объекты класса Test будут упорядочены от большего к меньшему по полю Factor. Если окажется так, что в SortedSet уже есть элемент с Factor, равным вставляемому, то зависимости от значения AdditionalFactor мне нужно вставить его либо выше, либо ниже.
Есть следующая реализация IComparer:

```
public class FirstComparer : IComparer<Test>
{

  public int Compare(Test x, Test y)
  {
     if(x==null || y == null)
       return 0;
     
     if(x.Factor== y.Factor)
      return x.AdditionalFactor == 0? 1:-1;

     var result = y.Factor.CompareTo(x.Factor)
     return result;

  }
}
```

Класс Test:

```
  public class Test
    {
       public int Factor {get; private set;}
       public int AdditionalFactor {get; private set;}
       
       public Test(int factor, int additional)
       {
        Factor = factor;
        AdditionalFactor = additional;
       }
    }
```

Я создаю SortedSet:

```
var set = new SortedSet<Test>(new FirstComparer());
```

При вставке все работает хорошо, однако я заметил, что теперь я не могу удалить элемент, так как мой кастомный Comparer никогда не возвращает 0 (равенство объектов).

Подскажите, можно ли разрешить данную проблему в рамках Comparer или же нужно использовать не SortedSet, а писать собственную коллекцию?

Comment: как именно ты удаляешь? Какой объект передаешь? Тот, что был в сете или создаешь новый с теми же значениями полей?

Comment: Каждый раз создаю новый объект. и его вставляю в set Удаляю через set.Remove(t)

Comment: вот этот `t` который передаешь в remove - откуда берешь?

Comment: t=new Test(546734, 0);  t2=new Test(436433, 1); set.Add(t); set.Add(t2);

Comment: тогда ты можешь добавить проверку ссылок, в этом случае все нормаль удаляться будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените проверку

```
if(x.Factor== y.Factor && x.AdditionalFactor != y.AdditionalFactor)
      return x.AdditionalFactor == 0  ? 1:-1;
```

И можете удалить первое условие с null оно туда никогда не попадет

Comment: в условие с null, очевидно, попадет, если один из объектов будет null

Comment: Да если он добавит в список его. Только вот почему равенство? Чтоб не менять местами?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Мне не нужно сравнивать x.AdditionalFactor и y.AdditionalFactor, мне важен именно факт того, что x.AdditionalFactor == 0

Comment: Я чуть подправил условие, так чтоб 0 все таки когда нибудь был